# Building a lazy, impure id generator

Tags: clojure

I'd like to know how to create an infinite, impure sequence of unique values in Clojure.

```
(def generator ...) ; def, not defn
(take 4 generator) ; => (1 2 3 4)
(take 4 generator) ; => (5 6 7 8). note the generator's impurity.
```

I think that such a design could be more convenient than e.g. wrapping a single integer value into a reference type and increment it from its consumers, as:

- The proposed approach reduces the implementation details to a single point of change: the generator. Otherwise all the consumers would have to care about both the reference type (`atom`), and the concrete function that provides the next value (`inc`)
- Sequences can take advantage many clojure.core functions. 'Manually' building a list of ids out of an atom would be a bit bulky: `(take 4 (repeatedly #(swap! _ inc)))`

I couldn't come up with a working implementation. **Is it possible at all?**

Comment: `(repeatedly gensym)`.  Not what you were looking for, I know.  Or: `(repeatedly #(gensym ""))`, generates symbols that look like numbers.

Comment: Or for actual numbers: `(repeatedly #(Long. (str (gensym ""))))))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wrap a lazy sequence around an impure class (like a java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong) to create an id sequence:

```
(def id-counter (java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong.))

(defn id-gen []
  (cons
   (.getAndIncrement id-counter)
   (lazy-seq
     (id-gen))))
```

This works, but only if you don't save the head of the sequence.  If you create a var that captures the head:

```
(def id-seq (id-gen))
```

Then call it repeatedly, it will return ids from the beginning of the sequence, because you've held onto the head of the sequence:

```
(take 3 id-seq)
;; => (0 1 2)
(take 3 id-seq)
;; => (0 1 2)
(take 3 id-seq)
;; => (0 1 2)
```

If you re-create the sequence though, you'll get fresh values because of the impurity:

```
(take 3 (id-gen))
;; (3 4 5)
(take 3 (id-gen))
;; (6 7 8)
(take 3 (id-gen))
;; (9 10 11)
```

I only recommend doing the following for educational purposes (not production code), but you can create your own instance of ISeq which implements the impurity more directly:

```
(def custom-seq
     (reify clojure.lang.ISeq
            (first [this] (.getAndIncrement id-counter))
            (next  [this] (.getAndIncrement id-counter))
            (cons  [this thing]
                   (cons thing this))
            (more [this] (cons
                          (.getAndIncrement id-counter)
                          this))
            (count [this] (throw (RuntimeException. "count: not supported")))
            (empty [this] (throw (RuntimeException. "empty: not supported")))
            (equiv [this obj] (throw (RuntimeException. "equiv: not supported")))
            (seq   [this] this)))

(take 3 custom-seq)
;; (12 13 14)
(take 3 custom-seq)
;; (15 16 17)
```

Comment: Awesome :) While I generally value immutability, I wonder in which ways could an application's correctness suffer if we opted for reifying ISeq.

Comment: can you elaborate?  what needs to be changed?  (thanks for pointing it out btw)

Answer (score 2):

I had a fun time discovering something during answering your question. The first thing that occured to me was that perhaps, for whatever ultimate goal you need these IDs for, the [`gensym`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/gensym) function might be helpful.

Then, I thought "well hey, that seems to increment some impure counter to generate new IDs" and "well hey, what's in the source code for that?" Which led me to this:

```
(. clojure.lang.RT (nextID))
```

Which seems to do what you need. Cool! If you want to use it the way you suggest, then I would probably make it a function:

```
(defn generate-id []
  (. clojure.lang.RT (nextID)))
```

Then you can do:

```
user> (repeatedly 5 generate-id)
=> (372 373 374 375 376)
```

I haven't yet tested whether this will produce always unique values "globally"--I'm not sure about terminology, but I'm talking about when you might be using this `generate-id` function from within different threads, but want to still be sure that it's producing unique values.

Comment: +1 for diving into the Clojure impl, I just love learning how it works. But after `(def a (repeatedly generate-id))`, `(take 5 a)` will always return the same...

Comment: On looking again, I see that my answer is just a different way of doing what you already said you didn't want.

Answer (score 1):

this is another solution, maybe:

```
user=> (defn positive-numbers
          ([] (positive-numbers 1))
          ([n] (cons n (lazy-seq (positive-numbers (inc n))))))
#'user/positive-numbers
user=> (take 4 (positive-numbers))
(1 2 3 4)
user=> (take 4 (positive-numbers 5))
(5 6 7 8)
```

Comment: I don't think your solution (which is pretty amusing anyway) conforms to my request - it is pure!

Answer (score 0):

A way that would be more idiomatic, thread-safe, and invites no weirdness over head references would be to use a closure over one of clojures built in mutable references. Here is a quick sample I worked up since I was having the same issue. It simply closes over a ref.

```
(def id-generator (let [counter (ref 0)]
                (fn [] (dosync (let [cur-val @counter] 
                         (do (alter counter + 1)
                           cur-val))))))
```

Every time you call (id-generator) you will get the next number in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another quick way:

```
user> (defn make-generator [& [ii  init]]
  (let [a (atom (or ii 0 ))
        f #(swap! a inc)]
    #(repeatedly f)))
#'user/make-generator
user> (def g (make-generator))
#'user/g
user> (take 3 (g))
(1 2 3)
user> (take 3 (g))
(4 5 6)
user> (take 3 (g))
(7 8 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is hack but it works and it is extremely simple

```
; there be dragons !
(defn id-gen [n] (repeatedly n (fn [] (hash #()))))
(id-gen 3) ; (2133991908 877609209 1060288067 442239263 274390974)
```

Basically clojure creates an 'anonymous' function but since clojure itselfs needs a name for that, it uses uniques impure ids to avoid collitions. If you hash a unique name then you should get a unique number.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Creating identifiers from an arbitrary collection of seed identifiers:

```
(defonce ^:private counter (volatile! 0))

(defn- next-int []
  (vswap! counter inc))

(defn- char-range
  [a b]
  (mapv char
        (range (int a) (int b))))

(defn- unique-id-gen
  "Generates a sequence of unique identifiers seeded with ids sequence"
  [ids]
  ;; Laziness ftw:
  (apply concat
         (iterate (fn [xs]
                    (for [x xs
                          y ids]
                      (str x y)))
                  (map str ids))))

(def inf-ids-seq (unique-id-gen (concat (char-range \a \z)
                                        (char-range \A \Z)
                                        (char-range \0 \9)
                                        [\_ \-])))

(defn- new-class
  "Returns an unused new classname"
  []
  (nth inf-ids-seq (next-int)))

(repeatedly 10 new-class)
```

Demonstration:

```
(take 16 (unique-id-gen [\a 8 \c]))
;; => ("a" "8" "c" "aa" "a8" "ac" "8a" "88" "8c" "ca" "c8" "cc" "aaa" "aa8" "aac" "a8a")
```